# Android ListView Single Choice Mode with Action Mode

Tags: android, listview

I would like to create an app screen that include one ListView.
When the user performs long press on ListView item, I would like to show action mode. I implemented it with the following code and I got the result which I want.

One problem is that I would like to allow the user to select only one list item and select the context menu item in action mode to do the operation. The following code is allowed the user to select multiple list items.

Is android not support ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE_MODAL choice mode? I had spend a lot of time in Googling but can't find any reference to implement which allows a single choice mode with context action mode. Please help.

```
        mTestListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        mTestListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long l, boolean value) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_test_single_choice_mode, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;                    
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_done:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        actionMode.finish();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your method. This code will check item count. If count exceed more than one, it will remove other item except the last one.

```
     public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                          long id, boolean checked) {
        int selectCount = mList.getCheckedItemCount();

        if(selectCount > 1){

            SparseBooleanArray checkarr = mList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i=0;i<dataList.size();i++){
                /*
                check item is checked
                and not the last item
                * */
                if(checkarr.get(i) && position != i){
                    mList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried in my app. It works. :). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Hein Htet Aung. You save me :-)

Comment: Sorry, I have another issue. When I call mList.getSelectedItem() in onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem), null is always returned.

Comment: Sorry, my  mistake :-( mList.getSelectedItem() always return null and I implement like the following and I got the correct selected position. Thanks :-) 'for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                if (mList.isItemChecked(i)) {
                                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(i);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }'

Comment: I think this way is not effective. What if I have the size of listView's data more than 100500 items (via the CursorAdapter) ? In my opinion, the loop should be performed on `checkarr` entries only.

Comment: Yep thanks for the point. :). It depends on the situation.There are other solutions like this, You can save the checked items in temp list so that you doesn't need to search 100500 items to uncheck.